# Help with an AJAX request

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

***The Problem***
I am tring to do an ajax request to a PHP script, however I am having a problem getting the data into the format that the PHP is expecting it, the PHP is expecting the data to come in as array within an array something like,

```
Array
(
    [cv_file] => Array
        (
            [849649717] => Y
            [849649810] => Y
        )

    [save] => Save CVs
)
```

**What have I tried?**

I have tried in my javascript to create an empty array and use that as the array key, something like this,

```
    var cv_file = new Array();
$(".drag_check").draggable({helper:"clone", opacity:"0.5"});
$(".searchPage").droppable({
    accept:".drag_check",
    hoverClass: "dropHover",
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
        var droppedItem = ui.draggable.children();
        cv_file = ui.draggable.children().attr('name');
        var link = ui.draggable.children().attr('name').substr(ui.draggable.children().attr('name').indexOf("[")+1, ui.draggable.children().attr('name').lastIndexOf("]")-8)
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST", 
            url:"/search",
            data:cv_file+"&save=Save CVs",
            success:function(){
                alert(cv_file)
                $('.shortList').append('<li><input type="checkbox" value="Y" class="checkbox" name="remove_cv['+link+']"/><a href="/cv/'+link+'">'+link+'</a></li>');
            },
            error:function() {
                alert("Somthing has gone wrong");
            }
        });

    }
});
```

**My Question**

How can I get the data into the format that the PHP is expecting, I would appreciate any help that anyone can give?

**Edit**
On alerting what the poster in the comments suggested I get he following,

`cv_file[849649717]&save=Save CVs`

Thank you

Comment: Alert out the result of the following expression before POST'ing, and edit your question with the results. `cv_file+"&save=Save CVs"` - i.e. `window.alert(cv_file+"&save=Save CVs");`

Comment: added the alert to my example

Answer (score 1):

To get the results in a PHP array in the back-end PHP file, you need to create a string like the following to POST back to the server:

```
cv_file[]=849649717&cv_file[]=849649810&save=Save CVs
```

I don't think you can create an associative array using this method, but the above should give you an array like the following in the `$_POST`:

```
Array
(
    [cv_file] => Array
        (
            0 => 849649717
            1 => 849649810
        )

    [save] => Save CVs
)
```

Then you can just do a foreach:

```
foreach ($_POST['cv_file'] as $cv)
{
    // Do something with $cv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could stringify your Array/Object, then do a [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) on the PHP side to convert the string back to an array.

EDIT : now with the correct PHP function.

Answer (score 0):

Use $(form).serializeArray() to build an array of the POST data. [serializeArray API doc](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)